# Once my tumbleweed question is automatically deleted, can I ask it again?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, automatic-deletion

I asked a question with MCVE that demonstrates problem I have no idea to fix. I was able to reproduce it on different servers (it's PHP thing), I provided input, output whole source and online demo.

I got 12 views (most of which are probably mine) and no votes, comments or answers. AFAIK, the system deletes inactive questions after some while. However I don't think I asked a bad question - I think I was just unlucky no PHP guru was online when I posted it.

Is it wrong if I repost it (or similar questions that do not lack research and problem description) if I'm unlucky to get people to even look at the question(s)?

Comment: Sounds entirely reasonable to me but it seems unlikely that no PHP follower looked at it. How long was it up? Does the title need work to make it more attractive. Perhaps consider adding a bounty?

Comment: It's up for exactly one week. I didn't want to post the specific question here, but maybe it might help if you review it and tell me what can I improve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929656

Comment: I confess no knowledge of the subject and I'm not clear as to the purpose of the operation but character glyph sizes (and their surrounding spaces) is quite complex.

Comment: Start with a bounty of 50. Then do 100. Then 200. Then 400 or 500. I'd be surprised if you didn't have an answer after four weeks of bounty.

Comment: FYI - I'm pretty sure the views count only tracks visits from unique IP addresses. You can view a question over and over and the count won't go up. OK, here's how it really works: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297001/how-stackoverflow-maintains-the-number-of-views-per-post

Comment: You can edit it which will bump it up to active, if you don't want to go for a bounty yet.

Comment: @Raystafarian I actually edited it a few times - but is this even legitimate way to edit questions?

Comment: If you're improving the question it's entirely legitimate.

Comment: @TomášZato..did your tumbleweed medal get revoked after the comments and the number of views it got after this post?

Comment: I already received tumbleweed medal for different post 2 years ago, so no :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Unless your question has a negative score, it won't be automatically deleted for at least a year. See the criteria [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

A year is quite a long time, you'll probably want to raise one or more bounties first, and perhaps try to improve the question a bit if possible at all.

If it's deleted after a year of no answers, you're free to post it again if you still want an answer to the question, but the chance of receiving an answer then will probably be quite low.

Comment: So am I the only one who is curious how this particular question got deleted after a week?

Comment: @TJ: It's *not* deleted yet, see the 2nd comment on the question.  The OP was expecting it to be deleted much sooner, hence this question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh thanks, I misread it. I didn't really expect someone with `10k`+ rep to ask "my question only got 12 views can I post it again once it gets deleted?" instead of putting a bounty on it before it's deleted. Maybe it's a smart way to get peoples attention without spending any rep on bounty? ._.

Comment: @TJ Heh, maybe. Clever strategy.

Comment: Writing to meta is the cheapest and most effective way to get your question an answer (and probably some free upvotes/rep).

Comment: @totymedli It's also not objectionable provided it is not overdone. Sometimes questions just get forgotten; the person who knows how to answer happens to not see (or to be short of time, or …). OTOH, I usually avoid questions with bounties in the tags I track; if I knew the answers, I'd have already answered.

Comment: One of the functions of [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is to: _"Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention"_ I wonder how much that will amount to in a year.

Comment: @TJ Guys I didn't even include the question in the OP to avoid such accusations. When I was asked if I'm sure that my question isn't poor quality, I shared it. I think that's the equivalent of sharing MCVE when posting question on main site...

Comment: @TomášZato it's not an accusation or anything. It's just some idea that popped up into my evil mind when I realized your question isn't actually deleted yet. don't take it to heart